# How keep a loop result into a variable or list?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a question about how to keep a loop result into a variable or list?

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("demo.docx")

text = []

def Text():
    
    for para in all_paras:
        if para.style.name == 'Normal (Web)':
            print("<p>" +
                  para.text + '</p>')
            

        if para.style.name == 'Heading 1':
            doc_title = para.text
            print('<h1>' +
                  doc_title +'</h1>')
            

        if para.style.name == 'Heading 2':
            doc_title = para.text
            print('<h2>' +
              doc_title + '</h2>')

        if para.style.name == 'Heading 3':
            doc_title = para.text
            print('<h3>' +
              doc_title + '</h3>')

        if para.style.name == 'Heading 4':
            doc_title = para.text
            print('<h4>' +
              doc_title + '</h4>')

        if para.style.name == None:
            print("nao encontrado")
                   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Text()
```

The output below is correct, but I would like store all content into a variable. How can I do it?

Result:

< p>Ut sed nisl eget mi consectetur commodo. Ut vehicula ligula ac nibh
sollicitudin tempus. Integer dictum non enim vulputate euismod.
Phasellus maximus fermentum nibh nec pellentesque. Suspendisse pretium
vel quam nec tristique. Praesent gravida tellus a tortor dapibus
imperdiet. Sed viverra nunc in congue vulputate. In in ipsum pharetra,
auctor tellus a, posuere ipsum. Vestibulum eget tincidunt arcu,
lobortis varius eros. Morbi vestibulum efficitur commodo.</ p>

Comment: Is that what you intended for this: `text = []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `text.append` instead of `print`

> Ex: Change `print("your string")` to `text.append("your string")`

Then finally to make the text variable which is of type array to string, you can simply do `textString = '\n'.join(text)` after all the text.append statements if you want to use this as a string anywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much, and if I need use this in another function, Can I use:

def NewText():
    print(Text.textString)

Or I need define global variable before?

Comment: Yeah, maybe define a class with `text` as a class variable, then add two functions, one for appending the string to text variable and another function for converting the array to string. By using this approach, you can reuse the same class in other files as well.

Answer (score 0):

change all `print()`s in your code to `text.append()`

Comment: Yes, I had tried but I forgot to use textString = '\n'.join(text). Thanks